# AWS CloudFront SSL Certificate - MalformedCertificate error

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

I am facing problem when uploading SSL certificate to AWS IAM for cloundfront.
I think that the command is ok and files are OK but still it gives an error.

We are using the following command for uploading SSL certificate:

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name SSL-CloudFront --certificate-body Public.cer --private-key keyStore.pem --certificate-chain STAR_xxxxxx_com.ca-bundle --path /cloudfront/ICE_SSL/
```

Error:

> A client error (MalformedCertificate) occurred when calling the UploadServerCertificate operation: Unable to parse certi
>   ficate. Please ensure the certificate is in PEM format.

How can I fix that?

Comment: It could be that it is misunderstanding your file names.. have you tried prepending 'file://' before file names to indicate those are file paths?

Answer (score 6):

You can do two things.. first obviously check your cert is in .PEM format.

A **PEM certificate** should be ASCII-readable. It needs to start with
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----, then there is base64-encoded data, and it must end with a line -----END CERTIFICATE-----.

Then make sure you add a **file://** before the file names in the command line parameters. Here is an example:

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name TestCert --certificate-body file://server.crt --private-key file://privatekey.pem
```

Comment: I was not using file:// prior to file name and it was giving error as file is not in PEM format. But it should give error as command line are incorrect.