# aws iam upload-server-certificate MalformedCertificate Unable to parse certificate. OSX

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, openssl, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

I keep getting this error and no more details.

Firstly I verified that the key matches the crt I'm using with the commands:

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in server.crt | openssl md5
$ openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in server.key | openssl md5
```

found [here](https://kb.wisc.edu/middleware/page.php?id=4064)

I'm using the command:

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name server --certificate-body /path/to/cert.crtt --private-key /path/to/key.key  --certificate-chain /path/to/bundle.ca-bundle --path /cloudfront/production/
```

I generated my csr and key using a command i found [here](https://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/generate-a-csr-with-openssl)

```
openssl genrsa -out ~/domain.com.ssl/domain.com.key 2048
```

Then the entire process again with the command

```
openssl req -new -key private-key.pem 2048 -out csr.pem
```

Consistently I get the same error message

```
A client error (MalformedCertificate) occurred when calling the UploadServerCertificate operation: Unable to parse certificate. Please ensure the certificate is in PEM format.
```

This question: [AWS CloudFront SSL Certificate - MalformedCertificate error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677051/aws-cloudfront-ssl-certificate-malformedcertificate-error) says I need a file:// as a prefix to dirs but I am on osx. (although I did try that anyway)

I've also tried changing the file extensions to .pem

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure that your .crt file is in PEM format to begin with.  It should start with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and end with `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`.

If not you can do this to get the certificate text:

```
cat server.crt | openssl x509 > server.pem
```

If the file is not in PEM format and instead in DER format you can convert it using the following:

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in server.crt -out server.pem -text
```

Comment: It is in PEM format -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFVzCCBD+gAwIBAgIQE2Y/AcmP3pzvONehVYJZbzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCB
...
NO7nfpEVC3+XO37oXr5xfevK0hN2eOijzroT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: Have you verified there are no spaces before the new lines?  Amazon's PEM parser is incredibly picky compared to OpenSSL.

Comment: Also when supplying the file parameters with the `file://` protocol on them run the command from the same directory as the files.  For some reason I have had better luck with that.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you are on windows or not... the path had to be file:///Users/my-home/path/tofile